# Create a new system namespace for a process in python

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, linux-namespaces

How can I change the system namespace value of a process created by `subprocess.Popen` in Linux environment?

Need to set following namespaces just after `subprocess.Popen(sys.argv[1:])`

- syscall.CLONE_NEWUTS
- syscall.CLONE_NEWPID
- syscall.CLONE_NEWNS

Comment: `unshare()` can be used for `CLONE_NEWUTS` and `CLONE_NEWNS`, but (obviously) not for `CLONE_NEWPID`, since the new process already exists *after* `Popen()`. If you need that, you will need to hack `Popen()` to dispatch to `clone()` with the appropriate flags instead of the normal `fork()`.